# Using the same variables and continuing unittests between classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm half expecting somebody to flag this as a duplicate, but if it is, I can't find the relevant question.

I have a situation where I have 2 test classes, where ClassA requires setup x and ClassB reuses the setup x, but also has an extra step y.

```
import my_module as m

class TestClassA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp()
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        self.d = m.initialiase_function(self.a, self.b, self.c)

    def test1(self)
        pass

    def test2(self)
        pass

class TestClassB(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp():
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        self.d = m.initialise_function(self.a, self.b, self.c)
        m.complete_function(self.c)

    def test3(self):
        pass

    def test4(self):
        pass
```

I've tried using `setUpModule()`, but this just means I need a load of `global` statements as well in each of the test classes, and that doesn't seem like the correct `pythoninc´ way of doing things either.

I also tried putting all the tests in the same class, so they shared the setup from `ClassA`, then called `m.complete_function()` as part of `test3`, but then my tests wouldn't run.

In this particular instance it's probably not a massive overhead to do setup and teardown twice, but I would like to work out the "correct" way of doing this for future reference as well.

Comment: You could extract a mixin class that implements the common setUp, then inherit from that (along with TestCase) in your test classes.

Comment: Hmm, I'll give that a go, but wouldn't that still do the setup and teardown twice? Even if it does adhere better to DRY principles.

Comment: Do you want to avoid duplicate definition or execution of the setup?

Comment: Ideally, both. As I say, in this case it's not a huge overhead to perform duplicate setup, and I will if I can't find a solution, but I can't help feel there should be a way to avoid that. @jonrsharpe 's comment addresses the duplicate definition issue, so worst case scenario, I will go with that.

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are local variables, how can they be relevant to the tests? Should they be instance variables instead? I think you need to post an example that is closer to what you really need.

Comment: @Goyo - you're right, but I messed up simplifying the question. I've added `self.` to the vars in the setUp process...

Comment: It's important to know that `setUp` (and `tearDown`) are executed before *each* test method. So if your intention is to prevent the overhead of setup and teardown for each test method you might want to look at `setUpClass` (and `teardownClass`).

Comment: Hi @jaap3. Thanks - and yes, since I wrote the question I have actually discovered those, and have changed my setUp() to setUpClass().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: Factor out the common code so that it's in a separate function, and call it (with `self` as an argument and slightly different configuration options if that fits your situation) from each of the `setUp()` methods. That avoids duplicating the definition.

If you also want to reuse the state you create, you need a variable in a shared namespace somewhere that can store the created state. Usually this would be a singleton, attached on the module level or to some common superclass; but you could also set up some registry object to hold the references, so that you can have multiple instantiations alive simultaneously. **However,** in my experience each test will usually do its own setup, even if it means duplicate effort, to ensure that the "fixture" has not been inadvertently modified by earlier tests.

Comment: "However, in my experience each test will usually do its own setup, even if it means duplicate effort, to ensure that the "fixture" has not been inadvertently modified by earlier tests." - I think I'm starting to realise that this is how I should be looking at this case, and that DRY is perhaps not to be so strictly applied in unit tests ...

Comment: DRY is about not repeating yourself _in code,_ which is a good idea-- so the refactoring you asked about is fine. Repeated calls are another matter (and I wouldn't risk the integrity of your tests just to shave a bit off the execution time).